# MySQL Database not updated after registration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

First of all I am new to Laravel framework, so please bear with me. I am creating an e-commerce website and created a registration page. The problem is whenever I fill the registration form and press register button the page will refresh but the data I filled will not be updated in MySQL database.

the registration file.
**registration.blade.php**
`

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
@section('title', 'Register')

    <section class="login-page"> 
        <div class="login-form-box">
            <div class="login-title"> Register</div>
            <div class="login-form">
                <form action="{{route('register')}}" method="post">
                @csrf
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="name">name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="john" >

                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="email">email</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="name" placeholder="john@gmail.com" >

                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="password">password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="******" >

                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="passowrd_confirmation">confirm password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="passowrd_confirmation" placeholder="******" >

                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <button type= "submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Register</button>
                    </div>
                    

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
@endsection
```

`
Also, here the route file in laravel

**web.php**

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PagesController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', [PagesController::class, 'home'])->name('home');
Route::get('/cart', [PagesController::class, 'cart'])->name('cart');

//Auth
Route::get('/login', [AuthController::class, 'showLogin'])->name('login');
Route::get('/register', [AuthController::class, 'showRegister'])->name('register');
Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'postRegister'])->name('register');
```

And here is the file for registration functions
**AuthController.php**
`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    //show login page
    public function showLogin()
    {
        return view('pages.login');
    }

    //show register page
    public function showRegister()
    {
        return view('pages.register');
    }

     //register user
    public function postRegister(Request $request)
     {
        //validation
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|min:3|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:8|confirmed'
        ]);


        //registration
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),

        ]);


        //login user
        Auth::login($user);

        return back()->with('success','succesfully Logged in');
        
     }
    

    
}
```

`
here is my Database in phpmyadmin after filling the form:
[users database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IyBY.png)
I tried to use showRegister function in my AuthController.php in order to check if the data being filled can be seen in the webpage. However, I was not able to see anything.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you are not displaying any errors or your flashed 'message' in your form it seems ... how do you know if validation is failing or if the submission was successful from that view page?

Comment: Hi lagbox, actually I checked after filling the registration form to check users table in phpmyadmin and there's no new data added there.

Comment: how do you know if validation is failing? which it is failing by the way ... both paths that can happen in your method here both redirect 'back'

Answer (score 0):

### Display errors and old values

First of all, I suggest you to update your view to display errors when using validation, and display old values:

```
<div class="field">
  <label for="name">name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" placeholder="john" >
  @error('name')
    <div>{{$message}}</div>
  @enderror
</div>
```

If the validation has no success, no changes will be made. Try to display if the validation has passed:

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
  //validation
  $request->validate([
    'name' => 'required|min:3|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|min:8|confirmed'
  ]);

  dd("Validation passed!);
}
```

This will help you to find errors.

**Take a look at [the official Laravel validation documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to check validation errors messages in registration.blade.php file

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```